# Is there any way we can stop the animate in Jquery (also stop the complete call back function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think the issue is relative with queue in Jquery.
We can use clearQueue() to clear queue to stop any animate, however the clear queue cannot stop the call back function
consider this

```
$("#sth").animate( { width:'100%' }, 2000, function() {
    $("#sth").css("width","0%");
});
```

and

```
$("#sth").clearQueue().css("width","0%");
```

is able to stop the animate and push back the width. However, after 2000 miliseconds, it will also turn to 100% width, because of the complete call back function. the function will invoke after 2000 miliseconds no matter whether the queue exists.

Comment: i try stop(), however it seems also cannot stop the callback, need i try both, clearQueue and also stop

Comment: oh,i c, seems like the issue of jumptoEnd.... haha got it

Comment: Yeah, it is explained in the documentation ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent callback if animation is stopped in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442550/how-to-prevent-callback-if-animation-is-stopped-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery documentation:

> .clearQueue()
>   Remove from the queue all items that have not yet been run.

and

> .stop()
>   Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Try use .stop() instead .clearQueue().

Answer (score 0):

calling stop function will stop the animation that was attached on sth obj

```
function stopSthAnim(){
    $('#sth#).stop(); 
}
```

you can also use complete callback function

```
$("#sth").animate( { width:'100%' }, {
        duration:2000,
        complete: function(){
           $('#sth#).stop(); 
        }
    }, function() {
    $("#sth").css("width","0%");
});
```